# jQuery Cycle2 issue on touch devices (click event will not fire)

Tags: jquery, events, click, touch, jquery-cycle2

I'm using jQuery Cycle2 with HTML content slides. Everything works OK except the elements inside the slides that I want to bind with jQuery click() event. On desktop PCs the event will fire but not on touch devices!

```
            <div class="slider_wrapper cycle-slideshow" 
                data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" 
                data-cycle-timeout="5000"
                data-pause-on-hover="true"
                data-cycle-swipe="true"
                data-cycle-prev="article section.slider .slider_wrapper .prev"
                data-cycle-next="article section.slider .slider_wrapper .next"
                data-cycle-slides="> div.slide">

                <div class="prev"></div>
                <div class="next"></div>
                <div class="cycle-pager"></div>

                <div class="slide">

                    <div class="image">
                        <div class="copyright"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text">
                        <div class="wrapper">

                            <h2>Title</h2>

                            <p>Some text</p>

                            <p><a class="more">Read More &raquo;</a></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

So what I want to do is to bind the a.more -link:

```
            $(".more").click(function() {   
// do something
            });
```

But this has no effect on touch devices!

Comment: for more information: any link inside of Slider  does not seem to work on touch devices!

Comment: try to paste a working example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), makes it way easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that touch events do not trigger click events in jquery. You will need to capture the touch event as a Tap and have the Tap trigger a click event. The following code allows you to register a tap event and bind it to your already existing touch events. The following function defines a tap as when a user touches element for longer than x and shorter than y time - in this case 50ms and 300.

To use: Give any element you want to make "touchable" a class of "touchable" and any touch events that bubble up from body tag will trigger the click event you already registered for that element. So in your case you would add touchable to your "more" element's class list.

```
    $("body").on("touchstart", ".touchable", function() { //make touchable  items fire like a click event if they bubble up from within body tag- can be any tag
    var d1 = new Date();
    var n1 = d1.getTime();
    setTimeout(function() {
    $(".touchable").on("touchend", function(event) {
        var d2 = new Date();
        var n2 = d2.getTime();
        if (n2 - n1 <= 300) {
        $(event.target).trigger("click"); //dont do the action here but instead call real/original click handler for this element
    }
    });
    }, 50)}).on("click", "#myelement", function() {
    //all the behavior i originally wanted -- this is optional -- you presumably already have click events bound to your elements
    });
```